# .NET API HttpRequestMessage not setting Header Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

We have an front-end application that authenticates through a third party.

We also have an API with an endpoint that receives requests from this front-end application.

To validate the token sent from our front-end application (and issued by the third party), our API is grabbing the token in the Authorization Header of the request from our front-end application and setting it in the Authorization Header of a separate request we are making to that third party to validate the token (they have an endpoint specifically for this).

When we make the request in Postman, we get back a `isValid: true` response indicating that the token we provided was issued by them & is valid. However, if we make this same request from our API, we are getting a `no token provided` error (this is the same error we get in postman if we do not include a token in the authorization header of our request).

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<bool> IsValidTokenRequest(string token)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _config["ThirdParty:URI"] + "/api/security/token");
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var isValidResponse = response.DeserializeResponseBody<IsValidTokenResponse>();

    return isValidResponse.IsValid;
}
```

We have also tried setting the Headers like:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
```

When we put a breakpoint on the `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);` line, we see the Authorization Headers are set in the 'request' object. However, we place our next breakpoint at the next line (`response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`), and the `response.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization` is `null`.

Its like our API is clearing out the request headers when it makes the request? Does anyone have any idea how/why this could be happening?

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to intercept the message and compare the headers

Comment: Like Charlieface said capture with Fiddler (or wireshark) and compare working request with non working request.  A good response should return a status of 200 OK.  A bad response will give sone other than 200.

Comment: Do I need to configure something in Fiddler? Even when I make a successful request in postman (and I am most definitely setting an Authorization Header) , Fiddler says "No Authorization Header is present' in the 'Auth' tab of the request. -- a problem trying to troubleshoot the problem...